# Python code snippet does not run

Tags: arcpy

I am new to programming in ArcMap, and am using ArcMap 10.5.
When I use the tool Select (Extract-Analysis Tool), the result is what I expect. 
However, When I run the Phyton Snipped code ArcMap displays:
“Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)”
I have searching the web with no success. Can you tell me how to fix this error?
On the other hand, I have to apply the tool 130 times to export the polygons shapes one by one. How can I include the code in a for cycle?

```
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features="D:/AKKGIS/cogo_plgs/001_130_cg_plgs.shp", out_feature_class="D:/ AKKGIS/img_clips/001_clp.shp", where_clause='"ppg_id" = '001'')
```

Comment: Remove the space in out feature class path

Answer (score 7):

You should change `where_clause` into `where_clause='"ppg_id" = \'001\''`. (added backward slashes)

You should use apostrophes and double quotes in right way. Please refer to that  post: [Arcpy query not working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352221/arcpy-query-not-working)